# SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table1.value AS table2

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

i have a db like this:

Table1:

- id
- id_item
- table (enum: 'table2','table3','table4')

table2:

- id
- value

table3:

- id
- value

table4:
[...]

And i want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.value FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table1.table as t2 ON t1.id_item=t2.id
```

Is it possible? or i have to select first table1 and after the value?
( sorry for my bad eng :) )

Comment: If you want to run this query, why wouldn't you just run it?

Comment: try it first and then tell us the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the last column in Table 1 correctly and it is just a string, you can't.

You cannot write a column into the `FORM`-clausal and wait for mysql to evaluate it for every row and find the correct table to join it with.

To do this you will need to create a view where you will have the data from all the tables, together with the table name as an additional column. Afterwards you can perform a join like that between Table1 and the new view